# Pass Vars from Django template to views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Im creating a filter for product categories and would like to pass the category name from the appropriate image on my template.
Part of the filter bar:

```
 <a href="{% url 'product-filter' MISC%}">
    <img src="{% static 'store/images/skateboard.png' %}" alt="">
 </a>
```

Urls:

```
path('search/<category>/', store_views.product_filter ,name='product-filter'),
```

I want MISC from the template to pass and become the category so that i can use it in views:

```
# ? Filter Products by Catagory
def product_filter(request, category):
    products= Product.objects.all()
    filter=ProductFilter(category,queryset=products)
    context={'products':filter}
    return render(request,'store/filter.html',context)
```

Getting this currently even just on my home page:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'product-filter' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/(?P<category>[^/]+)/$']
```

And this when on /search/MISC:

```
NoReverseMatch at /search/MISC/

Reverse for 'product-filter' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/(?P<category>[^/]+)/$']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url routing is not matching. Your error is in **category**.

```
path('search/<category>/', store_views.product_filter, name='product-filter'),
```

**FIX**:- Give the data type to *category* or any regex. Like:

```
path('search/<str:category>/', store_views.product_filter, name='product-filter'),
```

Comment: I belive Django defaults to str anyway

Comment: Well adding str: changed nothing

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Adding quotes to the url in template seemed to fix the home page but still getting no reverse match when link is clicked. Doesnt seem to be passing argument possibly?
New Link:
`<a href="{% url 'product-filter' 'MISC' %}">`

Comment: Will you check ```<a href="{% url 'product-filter' category='MISC' %}">```

Comment: Same issue 
`with arguments '('',)'`
The URL works and goes to /MISC but the url.py doesnt seem to be working

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 

    # ? STORE
    path('',include('store.urls') ),
    path('product/new/', staff_member_required(ProductCreateView.as_view(), login_url='login'), name='product-create'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/update/', ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='product-update'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/delete/', ProductDeleteView.as_view(), name='product-delete'),

    path('<str:category>/', store_views.product_filter ,name='product-filter'),

Comment: In the last line it is: ```path('<str:category>/', store_views.product_filter ,name='product-filter'), ```. Should be: ```path('search/<str:category>/', store_views.product_filter ,name='product-filter'), ```

Comment: Goes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/MISC/
But same error
`NoReverseMatch at /search/MISC/

Reverse for 'product-filter' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/(?P<category>[^/]+)/$']`